# Whatspp crashing with certain number Lumia 420

Tags: whatsapp

I lost my iphone at the weekend and decided to go for a windows phone. It now crashes with the same number I used for whatsapp...

With my old UK and UAE number it is fine but with the UAE Iphone number is keeps crashing after verification.

I have tried the basics: Reinstalling, resets and even another handset in store with no success.

Any suggestions are greatly apprciated.

Regards

Ben

Answer (score 1):

If u import a whatsapp account from iphone then it usually crashes on Windows Phone.
Solution:
If u have an android phone, use that particular number to sign in for whatsapp, use it for some hours. Then migrate your whatsapp account to the windows phone.